# How can I repair the Radio Module in Survival Planet

Tags: survival-planet

In the jungle (third area) you come across a broken radio module, and you have the chance to fix it by linking channels + or - in the circuit.

When I attempt to repair it, I see the schematics, tap and swipe around the circuit but nothing happens.

How do I go about repairing the radio? I'm more interested in how to interact with it than the solution, but the solution too is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must press very close to either the positive or negative ends of the cable and the terminal that they lead to.

SPOILER!

> *There are several stages of repair.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured out after posting, but your answer is correct.